# Variables in Ruby

Tags: ruby, variables

i would play a bit with Ruby.

Now i have a little problem, which i cannot solve.

The code:

```
@href = "http://localhost:3000"

def link(title, href)

  if href.nil?
    href = @href
  else
    href = href
  end

  output = "<a href=\"#{href}\">"
  output << "#{title}"
  output << "</a>"

  puts output

end

alias link_to link

link_to("Google","")
```

Whats the problem in my code?
I want set a default value for the href,if it is nil.

Greets,

Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here

```
>> "".nil?
=> false
```

You should use `.nil? or .empty?` as the condition.

```
>> "".empty?
=> true
```

Comment: if you do both conditions, both of these will work: `link_to("Google", nil);link_to("Google", "")`

Answer (score 2):

Here's a cleaner way to set the default:

```
def link(title, href = 'http://localhost:3000')
   # ...
end
```

Answer (score 1):

"" != nil

```
[10] pry(main)> link "xxx",nil
<a href="http://localhost:3000">xxx</a>
=> nil
```